# on clicking radio button it should show the correct item and hide all else

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a page which consist of some product categories with price, name, rating. Also in my side bar i have a filtering option. These are options by using radio button. On clicking any one of the radio button it should should the same product and hide all other products. How  ths can be achieved this filtering?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myfilter',
  pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], criteria: filterCriteria): any[] {
    if (!value || !criteria)
      return value;

    if(criteria.doFilter){
        return true;
    } else return items.filter(item => item.teamName.indexOf(filter) !== -1);
  }

}

export interface filterCriteria {
  property: string;
  descending?: boolean;
}
```

you need to add 2 formControls. One for radio button and one for filter.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Search" #search [formControl]="searchValue">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-radio-group [formControl]="doFilter">
  <mat-radio-button value="true">true</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button  value="false">false</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

in your TS create these formControls.

```
 searchValue = new FormControl('');
 doFilter = new FormControl(false);
```

In your ngFor you add the filter pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let eachitem of myItems | myFilter:{ searchValue: searchValue.value, doFilter: doFilter.value }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will hide radio buttons which are not selected.

```
 <div *ngIf="radio == undefined || radio !== (i+1)">
   <input type='radio' value='{{i+1}}' name='radio' id='radio{{i+1}}' [(ngModel)]="radio" (click)="radio()" />
 </div>
```

if you don't want use another div then use *`[hidden]`* attribute of input tag with same condition.

Hope this helps.. :)